# How would I edit tkinter font attribute on a custom entry object?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, fonts

I am trying to customise a Tkinter Entry Box. I have created a class inheriting from `tk.Entry`.

Here is the current code for the class:

```
class CustomEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, label="Enter a task", **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        self.label = label
        
        self.on_exit()
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_entry)
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.on_exit)
        
    def on_entry(self, event=None):
        if self.get() == self.label:
            self.delete(0, tk.END)

    def on_exit(self, event=None):
        if not self.get():
            self.insert(0, self.label)
```

I would like to be able to change the font/font color of the object withing the custom class code.

For example, in `on_entry` method, I would like to be able to change the weight of the font or the color.

Happy to provide more details.

**EDIT 1:** Just to clarify, I would like to edit the previously given arguments/attributes upon creation of the object for example editing the `font=self.customfont1` in `tk.Entry(self, font=self.customfont1).pack()` to lets say `font=self.customfont2` but within the actual object class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `self.configure(font=...)`, giving it whatever font specification you want.

Comment: I completely forgot about that being an option, thanks!